# Exception on opening DataSet Visualizer due to the AssemblyResolve event

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, .net-core, reflection

When trying to use the magnifing glasson one of my `DataSet` or `DataTable` in my **.Net Core 3.1** WPF Project I get a `System.IO.FileLoadException` with following text:

> Could not load file or assembly 'DataSetVisualizer.DebuggeeSide, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. General Exception (0x80131500)

Stack trace:

```
at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, RuntimeAssembly assemblyContext, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, AssemblyLoadContext assemblyLoadContext)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, AssemblyLoadContext assemblyLoadContext)
at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(AssemblyName assemblyRef, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, AssemblyLoadContext assemblyLoadContext)
at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(AssemblyName assemblyRef)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers.DebuggeeSide.Impl.ClrCustomVisualizerDebuggeeHost..ctor(String debuggeeSideVisualizerTypeName, String debuggeeSideVisualizerAssemblyName, String[] probePaths)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers.DebuggeeSide.Impl.ClrCustomVisualizerDebuggeeHost.Create(String debuggeeSideVisualizerTypeName, String debuggeeSideVisualizerAssemblyName, String[] probePaths)
```

I narrowed the cause for this problem down to my recently implemented method to load assemblies from subfolders at runtime, which I wrote based on **Reza Aghaei**'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60150045/7696590) on my last question.

In narrowed it down to the subscription on the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve` event, but couldn't find a way to solve it yet.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (obj, arg) =>
{
  var name = $"{new AssemblyName(arg.Name).Name}.dll";
  var assemblyFile = referenceFiles.Where(x => x.EndsWith(name))
        .FirstOrDefault();
  if (assemblyFile != null)
      return Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyFile);
  throw new Exception($"'{name}' Not found");
};
```

It doesn't matter if I am trying to view the `DataSet` in one of the loaded assemblies or the startup application.

I would like to keep working with this method to load assemblies at runtime, but since I am working with a lot of `DataSets` being able to use the *DataSet Visualizer* is crucial for me.

**Any suggestions?**

edit: usage of dataset visualizer during debugging:

[image]

Comment: How do you use *DataSet Visualizer*? At run-time?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your quick response. I added an image as how I am trying to use the DataSet Visualizer during debug. I made an empty sample project with noting but your code from my other question. If I change `throw new Exception($"'{name}' Not found");` to `return null;`, it seems to work, although I fear this might be a problem for the initial usage of this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an elegant solution, but as a workaround to unblock your debugging sessions, add the following to the beginning of the [`AssemblyResolve`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) event handler:

```
#if DEBUG
    if (arg.Name.StartsWith("DataSetVisualizer"))
        return null;
#endif
```